# DNS name server IP keeps reverting back to unknown for forward lookup zone

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, windows-server-2012, domain-name-system

I'll start by saying I have not worked much with DNS and DC's. I'm a programmer who is trying to build out an environment with a domain to simulate a production scenario.

My issue is the forward lookup zone (FLZ) I have for my domain keeps dropping the A record that gets created for the domain. When I look within the name servers for the zone the name server has the FQDN of the DC (the same machine I'm running DNS on) but it says unknown for the IP. If I resolve it by going to edit and clicking "resolve" it will populate it with the correct IP and then when I apply it it will automatically add the appropriate A record and all is good for about 15 mins or until I reload the zone. Then it disappears again and none of my other servers can access the domain appropriately.

The _msdcs FLZ has always had the appropriate ip for the nameserver and it's been stable ever since I installed it. It's just the FLZ. I also added a reverse lookup zone and that one has kept the IP for the name server as well without any issues.

The environment is a Server 2012 VM which I'm running using Hyper V. I have configured a private virtual switch in Hyper V for my VM's to run on. The server I'm working on has a static IP assigned to it and I've disabled IPV6.

My ipconfig /all:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-01-06-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.223.13(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.223.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.223.13
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BFE28ADA-090D-4888-97B4-C6E6231C3F57}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

What could I be missing? I've been banging my head against this for awhile now.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: It looks to me like the DC has an APIPA assigned ip address. Try assigning a valid static ip address to the DC.

Comment: Thanks Joe - I did add a static IP within the settings and assigned it a default gateway and everything. Is there something more I need to do that I'm missing?

Comment: Hello. If you happen to log in again, please mark this question as answered so that it doesn't periodically show up on the front page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might have corrected it by changing my address from a 169.* address to a 10.* address which would probably make more sense given it's a private network with it's own DC/DNS server. Everything appears good so far, even after I reload and reboot the server. We'll see if this actually fixed it when I start working with it tomorrow.

Comment: Just for the record and as a rule of thumb, servers in your network need to be configured with manual/static IP addresses so they can be searched/queried to the same destination every single time.